# Windows could not search for new updates?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

I have a recently-built Windows Server 2008 R2 system whose Windows Updates started failing suddenly. While I am presented an error code **80072F76**, none of the [automatic fixes](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IL/windows7/Windows-Update-error-80072efe-or-80072f76) seem to work.

What's the best method to troubleshoot this? General internet access works as normal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is Automatically detect settings check box is selected in the LAN settings? IE > Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings

Comment: @cole Yes. It's checked.

Comment: Can you reboot the server? I've seen this issue before where it wouldn't connect (usually on a new installation) and a reboot usually fixes it.

Comment: Rebooted several times... No change.

Comment: This will sound silly, but is Windows activated properly?

Comment: Is there a WSUS server on the network by chance?  And are your firewalls running any IDS software on them?  I've seen (with Sonicwalls) that the IDS signatures will occasionally flag and block windows update traffic.

Comment: I've also seen Kaspersky Antivirus stop updates from happening, or the Windows Update service is set to manual.

Comment: I've seen UAC cause problems, try disabling UAC, reboot, update again

Comment: What DNS servers are you using?

Comment: @dirt Normal cocktail of local DNS with forwarded to ISP and Google DNS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And I found the source... a [Barracuda Web Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Q11.png) set to *block* Windows Updates...

Soooo wrong (another admin configured this)...

Administrators should understand this this is a *poor way* of managing bandwidth.

[image]

Comment: Barracuda is just that smart.

Comment: Maybe it was done on purpose because WSUS.  Proper GPO might still be needed. (Although that block sure looks global to me)

Comment: No WSUS, no AD domain (yet) and yes, it was a blanket global URL block.

Comment: Maybe the admin thought Windows Updates were on par with thedirty.com ;)

Answer (score 2):

The general place to start troubleshooting this error is [KB836941](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941). Following the steps in this KB article may resolve the problem, but probably won't, since the article indicates that `0x80072F76` corresponds to an API error `ERROR_WINHTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND`. This error, it turns out, means that there is an HTTP header that Windows Update is looking for but [wasn't present in the response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This, of course, indicates that Windows Update didn't actually connect successfully to the Windows Update server, but something in the middle interfered with the connection.

To resolve the issue, check the proxy servers and firewalls in the path between the server and the Internet to determine which one is blocking or mangling the connection. Also check for viruses and malware, as some of them target Windows Update to prevent updates from being installed.